# How to space-between two divs vertically using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I space-between two divs vertically using flexbox? Everything works when using it for the horizontal patterns, but not for the vertical ones.

```css
#container {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 15vw;
  background-color: lightblue;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">
    <p>Align Top</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Align Bottom</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the display of `#container` to `flex`, and set `flex-direction: column;`:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 15vw;
  background-color: lightblue;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">
    <p>Align Top</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Align Bottom</p>
  </div>
</div>
```